# What is the proper package.json manner to publish a npm package developed with Browserify?

Tags: node.js, npm, browserify

I am publishing a npm package developed with Browserify, and wonder what is the proper manner to construct a `package.json`.

The package is a node server-client app (it is actually [atom](https://atom.io) package), and the client side is based on [Browseriy](http://browserify.org).

`./www/js/index.js` -> `./www/js/index.bundled.js`

The required modules are [marked](https://github.com/chjj/marked) and [highlight.js](https://github.com/isagalaev/highlight.js).

The both modules are used only on the client side code/file which is bundled by blowserfiy.

A lazy and simple solution would be simply, just to have

**package.json A**

```
{
  ......,
  "dependencies":
  {
    ...,
    ...,
    "highlight.js": "*",
    "marked": "*"
  }
}
```

and to include the `www/js/index.bundled.js` file in the npm package files as it is after the browserify in my local dev environment.

However, now I think the npm package.json can be one of the below:

**package.json B**

```
{
  ......,
  "dependencies":
  {
    ...,
    ...,
  },
  "devDependencies":
  {
    "highlight.js": "*",
    "marked": "*",
    "browserify": "*"
  }
}
```

In this case, browserified `./www/js/index.bundled.js` file is left in the npm package, and treat `marked` and `highlight.js` as a devDependencies, and also `browserify`.

Then

**package.json C**

```
{
  ......,
  "dependencies":
  {
    ...,
    ...,
    "highlight.js": "*",
    "marked": "*",
    "browserify": "*"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "run": "browserify ./www/js/index.js -o ./www/js/index.bundled.js"
  }
}
```

Just let you know, I have never tried this, and don't know this scripts-run actually runs on `npm install myPackage`, perhaps not, and maybe you know the proper configuration, maybe there's no such a thing.

In this scenario, `./www/js/index.bundled.js` is excluded from the npm package file, and built from the latest npm packaged `marked` and `highlight.js`.

The reason I think this manner is somewhat proper is especially in the scenario the npm modules are used and shared in both server and client side.

For instance, take a look at [dnode](https://github.com/substack/dnode). This RPC module is developed by the same author of browserify (@substack), and should share the same version of dnode module in both server and client side. If a pre browserified `./www/js/index.bundled.js` is bundled in the published npm package, it will be outdated compared to server side dnode. Sure we may be able to specify the version to install by package.json, but it's better to use the latest on both server and client side.

Any suggestion? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use second choice and specify `browserify` as a devDependency.

You have to build it before you publish your package to npm registry, so users won't need to install browserify themselves.

It's also useful to add a `Makefile` and `make` as a prepublish script.

Comment: Thanks. I think this works when the modules are only used in the client side, and I wonder if some modules are shared between client and server side. Perhaps, in that case, we need to specify the version of the modules to sync.